# How to quantify the performance of an Android layout xml file

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-layout

I am a junior developer and I am somewhat puzzled about writing xml layout files.

There are many implementations for the UI layout of the same style, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout And Linearlayout, and so on. Different implementations have different nesting levels. We know that there are as few nesting levels as possible, and that LinearLayout is used instead of RelativeLayout for the same number of layers.

But careful analysis, how do we measure the A implementation of a layout is better than B, two layers of nested LinearLayout really do not have a RelativeLayout to save performance? How to determine this? By experience? But where does the experience come from? It may be a good way to read the source code, but it is more difficult.

I think it is possible to find a good way of writing by analyzing the rendering time of an xml layout file and comparing the time spent on different implementations.

So I would like to ask everyone, is this a feasible way?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about, how we check the rendering time. But check below URL's one after one it may help you to understand more about rendering and performance related.

1) https://medium.com/@elifbon/android-application-performance-step-1-rendering-ba820653ad3

2) http://adavis.info/2015/03/android-overdraw-what-is-it-and-why-should-you-care.html

If i find any way to check the rendering time surely will let you know.